# Automation Error when GetObject Outlook from Excel

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I'm writing a VBA code in Excel to send an Outlook mail based on some information in Excel file. 
Everything is OK, it works well on my computer and others. But there's one computer got error when I GetObject for Outlook Application.

The error is "Automation error"

The code looks like this:

```
Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
Dim oltask As Outlook.taskitem

On Error Resume Next
'check if Outlook is running - **The code stopped here**
Set olApp = GetObject("outlook.application")
If Err <> 0 Then
    'if not running, start it
    Set olApp = CreateObject("outlook.application")
End If

Set oltask = olApp.CreateItem(olTaskItem)
```

Comment: This can be caused by anti-virus software blocking automated access to Outlook.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but all of us are using the same "Symantec Endpoint Protection". And there's only one computer cannot get Outlook.Application

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but it's not work. I just re-install the computer and now the code's running well.

Comment: Thanks  -  https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/289619

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your reference are set up

Microsoft outlook Object Library

Microsoft Word Object Library

Microsoft excel object Library

[image]

```
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
```

Answer (score 0):

Initially i'd try something like...

1. Try to compile the code on the failing machine.
2. Try declaring the outlook definitions as Object. This will cause the software to lookup the code at runtime.

Looks more like a registration type issue to me specific to that p.c.